# How to track filter events in jqxgrid

Tags: php, jqxgrid

I am working with jqxgrid and PHP. In the jqxgrid i have problem with filter functionality. I want to know that is there any function that show me what filterting options i selected for filtering data.

I have a section below jqxgrid table. In which i want a some calculation based on that jqxgrid table data. When the user load a page firsttime then jqxgrid data and below calculations are correct. But when user make some filterization in jqxgrid table below calculation does not change. I want what filter options choose by user for filtering operation.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging lot in the jqxgrid documentation, I found the answer that how to get filterable data from grid table.

Basically jqxgrid provide this method for getting current table data.

```
var rows = $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('getdisplayrows');
```

You can use this method in your filter functionality and will get the filterable result.

```
$("#jqxgrid").bind("filter", function (event) {
            $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('autoresizecolumns');
            var rows = $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('getdisplayrows');
            showResults(rows);
        });
```

Now create a showResults() function in like this way.

```
<script>
function showResults(data) {
console.log(data);
// Do anything you want to do with current table data.
}
</script>
```